# Does anyone know how to host my own videos on Bluehost and creating links for it, so it would loop playing on my website?

Tags: video, hosting, bluehost

[I tried to post a photo here, but it's not working.]

This is what I've tried:

1. https://yukascreations.com/home4/simmtrmy/Public_html/Videos/Rada_video03.MP4
2. https://yukascreations.com/home4/simmtrmy/Videos/Rada_video03.MP4
3. https://yukascreations.com/Videos/Rada_video03.MP4

yukascreations.com is my Domain name.

I'm making a website on Tilda. I want to have my own video playing (looping) when I open the website. I bought my Domain and hosting through Bluehost.

I was able to upload the video to Bluehost, but I can't figure out how to create a link to it so that it would work when I enter the URL in the browser. I've tried different variations, but nothing is working. And I can't find any information about it anywhere.

I've entered different variations of what I thought the correct link could be, but nothing works. And there isn't one that is generated automatically or at least I couldn't find it.

For the video to work, it needs to have `...mp4` on the end of the link.

This is my first time writing here, so I'm not really sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and include examples of the code you have tried?  That will allow people to help you debug.